# QMenu modeless/async

Tags: c++, qt

QMenu can be created by using popup() or exec(). The former creates it asynchrously while the latter blocks. But this isn't useful when you're using a QMenuBar (AFAIK).

My question is, is it possible to tell QMenuBar to only popup asynchrous/modeless QMenus? I'm not sure the terms are correct, but all I want is a Menu that won't block the rest of the application when users click on it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Who blocks? The caller? While the menu is open (and automatically gets input focus), what would you expect to be able to do other than either close the menu or pick a menu item?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear in my description. When you click a menu in QMenuBar, the main thread is blocked until you leave the menu or click an item, for as long as the menu is shown. This results in the rest of the application freezing as the main loop no longer loops. This is fine for other Qt windows as these still receive paint events from Qt, but if you have other logic (like a connection, or a renderer) that relies on the main loop updating them, they'll freeze.

I recall there was a modeless flag for QMenuBar or QMenu, but can't for the life of me find any documentation on it anymore.

Comment: The term you are searching is "Modal Dialog" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: Nemanja: Please read the question before you post.

Kuba Ober: This is pretty much what I ended up with. I think I recalled that there was a switch for this, but it appears I was wrong. Thanks for the hint nevertheless!

Comment: What version of Qt are you running, and on what platform?  Modern versions of Qt (e.g. 4.0 or later) running on desktop platforms (e.g. Mac/Windows/Linux) should not block the GUI thread while the user is accessing the window's menu.

Comment: I'm using 4.8.3 on Windows 7.

The Qt GUI thread isn't blocked. When you click the menu, the next call to QApp::processEvebts() will block until the menu is hidden.

This results in any other code that needs to run every frame like the render loop, can't.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround you're looking for is to move your objects that can't live with such "abuse" to a separate QThread. If you have a clean interface using signals and slots, this is trivial. Just use `moveToThread()` and you're done. You don't need to worry about anything else.

Comment: I don't think that will work if the goal of the exercise is to e.g. keep an animation inside the window animating while the user deals with the menu.  Qt doesn't allow you to move GUI objects to another thread.

Comment: I'll dig into it, I have this very problem myself :(

Comment: My intention was that of which Jeremy described. I want the animation (in this case a rendered scene) to keep rendering even if I'm pressing the menu, ie. I want the main loop where the rendering happens to continue.

Comment: That's understandable. There is a workaround, but I have to check if it works on Windows too.